# In flutter I am not able to play uint8List type as audio when streaming via websocket with just_audio package

Tags: flutter, streaming, just-audio

Here is my code :

```
try {
      _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
          'wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/$voiceId/stream-input?model_id=$model');

      _channel!.stream.listen(
        (data) async {
          final response = jsonDecode(data);
          if (response['audio'] != null) {
            try{
              final audioChunk = response['audio'] as String;
              final uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(audioChunk));

              await _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(
                ConcatenatingAudioSource(
                  children: [
                    AudioSource.uri(


                      Uri.dataFromBytes(
                        uint8List,
                        mimeType: 'audio/mpeg',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
              await _audioPlayer.play();
            }
            catch (e){
              print("Error setting audio source and playing: $e");

            }
```

I am able to get the response and am converting it to uint8List and trying to play it but its not playing anything and I am getting error :

> flutter: Error setting audio source and playing: (-11828) Cannot Open
> flutter: Error setting audio source and playing:
> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method load on
> channel
> com.ryanheise.just_audio.methods.abaaa9b2-f8ed-4c88-9d89-4623ab523beb)
> flutter: Error setting audio source and playing: (-11828) Cannot Open

How can I play it? Is there any other package that can do it? I am successfully getting the response but am just not able to play it

Comment: Can you clarify your question with which platform/s you are targeting?

Comment: Sorry I am targetting both iOS and Android

Answer (score 1):

This example comes from the just_audio README:

```dart
// Feed your own stream of bytes into the player
class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final List<int> bytes;
  MyCustomSource(this.bytes);
  
  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}

await player.setAudioSource(MyCustomSource(...));
player.play();
```

You can define your own custom subclass of `StreamAudioSource` that feeds audio data into just_audio. Since part of the returned `StreamAudioResponse` is a stream, you can just transform and redirect your websocket stream into this `StreamAudioResponse`. So instead of:

```dart
Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
```

you could use something like:

```dart
channel!.stream
        .map(json.decode)
        .map((data) => data['audio'])
        .map(base64.decode),
```

Since this audio source would continuously stream the audio data to just_audio, you would just call `setAudioSource` once and not repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tried it. Its working but audio is not playing continuoulsy via stream. Is there a way I can keep feeding the player continuous stream of data that I am getting from elevenlabs

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for helping out but I am still confused. I understand I need to setAudioSource only once but I can't figure out how is it. possible. Can you please help me?

Comment: If you don't understand how streams work, that's probably outside the scope of this question. There are good tutorials online about streams. All I can tell you is that the code above defines a single stream of continuous audio THIS is the source of audio (hence why it is called an audio source). A different source of audio could be a file or an asset or a URL, but above it is a custom stream. Use Google to learn more about the finer details of each of these things.